# How to extract a URL from a twitch clip using RegEx in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

So I'm pretty bad at regex and I need to extract a link from a string.

Example:

```
str = 'hi check this https://clips.twitch.tv/KindYummyCarrotPeteZaroll clip!!'
```

I need to extract the full URL "https://clips.twitch.tv/KindYummyCarrotPeteZaroll" from the string.

The ID of the clip is "KindYummyCarrotPeteZaroll" which is different in every URL.

The `str` can have multiple links that get handled in a different way. We have to match https://clips.twitch.tv/ID.

Comment: Do you mean `https:\/\/clips\.twitch\.tv\/\S+`?

Comment: Yes this one is good, But how can we make the https part optional ? so it catches clips.twitch.tv/ID aswell as https://clips.twitch.tv/ID?

Comment: Wrap it in `(?:` and `)?` i.e. `(?:https:\/\/)?clips\.twitch\.tv\/\S+`

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code:

```js
var paragraph = 'hi check this https://clips.twitch.tv/KindYummyCarrotPeteZaroll clip!!';
var regex = /(?:https:\/\/)?clips\.twitch\.tv\/(\S+)/i;
var result = paragraph.match(regex);
console.log(result);
console.log('Clip ID: ' + result[1]);
```

The ID of the clip will be in `result[1]`.

Explanation:

- `(?:https:\/\/)?clips\.twitch\.tv\/` matches the exact string `https://clips.twitch.tv/` or `clips.twitch.tv/`, the question mark after the parentheses means 0 or 1 occurrence of the text inside the parentheses, `?:` means that we don't want to capture it, backslashes are there just to escape special characters
- `(\S+)` - `\S` matches any non-whitespace characters, `+` means one or more occurrences, parentheses are there so the matched text is returned in a separate field
- as a regular string is enclosed in (double-)quotes, the regex is enclosed in slashes
- there may be various modifiers after the closing slash, in our case it's `/i` which means case-insensitive matching

For further details on regular expressions, see the [documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to extract URLs from the string then split the `pathname` of each URL to obtain the username.

```
const str = "hi check this https://clips.twitch.tv/KindYummyCarrotPeteZaroll clip!! second url: https://clips.twitch.tv/foobar";

// match all URLs
// const urls = str.match(/\bhttps?:\/\/\S+/gi);

// match URLs with clips.twitch.tv
const urls = str.match(/\bhttps?:\/\/clips\.twitch\.tv\S+/gi);

for (let i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
    let a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = urls[i];
    let parts = a.pathname.split('/');
    console.log(urls[i], parts[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex :

`https:\/\/(?:clips|www)\.twitch\.tv\/(?:(?:[a-z]+)\/clip\/)?([a-zA-Z]+)`

Twitch clips can come in 2 shapes, `https://www.twitch.tv/<streamer_name>/clip/<clip_id>` and `https://clips.twitch.tv/<clip_id>`, in which streamer_name and clip_id always come as a string of alphabetic latin characters, both upper and lowercase.

With this regex, you can get the link itself in a string, and also the ID of the clip.

```js
const stringToTest = 'hi check this https://clips.twitch.tv/KindYummyCarrotPeteZaroll clip!!';
const match = /https:\/\/(?:clips|www)\.twitch\.tv\/(?:(?:[a-z])\/clip\/)?([a-zA-Z]+)/;

if (match != null && match.length > 1) {
  console.log(match[0]); // https://clips.twitch.tv/KindYummyCarrotPeteZaroll
  console.log(match[1]); // KindYummyCarrotPeteZaroll
}
```

Comment: I think you might've missed a `*` after `?:[a-z]` but overall good solution as it handles both formats

Comment: You are right, though I believe a `+` would be better. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this using substr and indexOf as follows

```
str = 'hi check this https://clips.twitch.tv/KindYummyCarrotPeteZaroll clip!!'
//get the starting location of the url 
var start = str.indexOf("https");
//get the ending location of url
var end = str.substr(start).indexOf(" ");
//get url using the starting and ending locations
var url = str.substr(start,end);
//get id from url in similar fashion
var id_start_location = url.lastIndexOf("/");

var id = url.substr(id_start_location);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex to match urls from that server:

```
/https://clips.twitch.tv/([^ ]*)/
```

The regex matches the host name followed by ID, which is captured in Group 1.

Use it like this:

```
var str = 'hi check this https://clips.twitch.tv/KindYummyCarrotPeteZaroll clip!!';
var regex = /https://clips.twitch.tv/([^ ]*)/;
var match = regex.exec(str); var url = match[0];
var url = match[0]; //url now contains the url
var id = match[1]; // id is now the id
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I come with two approaches. One is using arrays, the other one - regex.

```js
    const str = 'hi check this https://clips.twitch.tv/KindYummyCarrotPeteZaroll clip!!';
    
    // 1 Arrays approach
    const array = str.split(' ');
    
    array.forEach(item => {
      if (item.substr(0, 8) === 'https://') {
    
        const arrayFromSubstr = item.split('/');
    
        console.log(item);
        console.log(arrayFromSubstr[arrayFromSubstr.length - 1]);
    
      }
    });
    
    console.log('\n\n');
    
    // 2 RegEx approach
    const url = str.match(/https.+\s/)[0];
    console.log(url);
    
    const id = url.match(/\/{1}\w+(\w|\s)$/);
    
    console.log(id[0]);
```

Comment: I think u forgot this part "The str can have multiple links that get handled in a different way. We have to match https://clips.twitch.tv/ID."