# Twitch clip regex

Tags: regex, twitch

I was looking at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52633162/how-to-extract-a-url-from-a-twitch-clip-using-regex-in-javascript) but twitch has recently changed its url for clip into a different format.

The new format is:

```
https://www.twitch.tv/loserfruit/clip/HungryBillowingSandpiperTebowing
```

And the ID for the clip is HungryBillowingSandpiperTebowing

How could I extract the ID using regex?

My best attempt is by using replacing method, will such method be able to cover all the grounds?

```
  var Y = "/clip/";
  var X = twitchurl;
  var Z = X.replace(new RegExp(".*" + Y), "");
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `twitchurl.match(new RegExp(Y + "/([^/]+)"))[1]`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew getting a type error: Cannot read property '1' of null

Comment: Ah, there is a `/` already at the end of `Y`, so use `twitchurl.match(new RegExp(Y + "([^/]+)"))[1]`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, got it, appreciate your help, you can put that as the answer and I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You attempt to match any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible, before your `Y` (`/clip/` string).

Instead, you should match any one or more chars other than `/` as many as possible *after* the `Y` part, using `[^/]+`.

You may utilize either a lookbehind based solution or a capturing group one:

```js
const Y = "/clip/";
const twitchurl = "https://www.twitch.tv/loserfruit/clip/HungryBillowingSandpiperTebowing";
// Using a capturing group
const result = twitchurl.match(new RegExp(`${Y}([^/]+)`))?.[1];
console.log(result);
// Using a lookbehind
const result2 = twitchurl.match(new RegExp(`(?<=${Y})[^/]+`))?.[0];
console.log(result2);
```